# Is there an action that is called when changing the items per page in vuefity? :switch-items-per-page

Tags: vue.js

I have customized my tables with the following options:

```js
:items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
:footer-props="{
    'items-per-page-options': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, -1]
}"
```

The itemsPerPage are taken from the user's settings when the page is loaded. But now I would like if the user change the numbers in the table, save them as settings. Is there an event or function in vuefity, how to call this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `update:options` [event](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#events-update:options).

This event exposes the following data:

```
{
  page: number,
  itemsPerPage: number,
  sortBy: string[],
  sortDesc: boolean[],
  groupBy: string[],
  groupDesc: boolean[],
  multiSort: boolean,
  mustSort: boolean
}
```

So when the user changes the numbers in the table the above event will fire and you can save the selection to your user settings.